# Get the single value from mongodb Collection using java code

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get only the single value from Mongodb Collection.

Currently i am getting the Document which is FindIterable.

```
CustomObject obj =  db
        .getCollection("Collection",CustomObject.class)
        .find(and(eq("field1", new BigDecimal(10409)),eq("field2", new BigDecimal(1))));
```

But , i dont want any result in to the Object or List.like in Oracle we use Query to get single Object :

> **SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE ID=10 AND DEPT_ID=23;**

This query gives us the Single name of the employee on the basis of filter conditions, and we get the output in String type Object.

Same i want to get from the mongodb , i don't want to use any bean to populate the data. i want only single String object as result.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the find method on Collection, passing a query and fields to retrieve:

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
fields.put("name", true);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("id", 13);
query.put("dept_id", 23);

DBCursor find = mongoTemplate.getCollection("example").find(query, select);
List<DBObject> list = find.toArray();
List<String> names = list.stream().map(o -> String.valueOf(o.get("name"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but,I want only single String / BigDecimal type result i don't wanna any List or a bean type object for result.

Comment: + a one-liner to retrieve the column value form the DbObject.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood what you meant. Not a "single result", but rather a one-column result, changed the answer to reflect that. It's the only way I know as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking for a function that returns just one document, then you can use [`findOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).