# Searching with single query on mongoDB for java api

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

guys how to searching on multiple collections and multiple object on mongoDB for java api using one single query?

here i want to search `everest`

from table :

1. web1

have coloumn

> name
>
> age
>
> hoby

2. web2

have coloumn

> car
>
> home
>
> motorcycle

3. web3

have coloumn

> phone
>
> child
>
> office

on mysql for java api i usually using `SELECT *.a , *.b , *.c FROM a.web1, b.web2, c.web3 WHERE a.name=everest OR a.age=everest OR a.hoby=everest OR b.car=everest OR b.home=everest OR b.motorcycle=everest OR c.phone=everest OR c.child=everest OR c.office=everest`

i am begginner using mongoDB, its so very different between mongoDB and mySQL...
please show me the script mongoDB for java api about this query...

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking, but take a look at this, this seems similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328982/get-the-single-value-from-mongodb-collection-using-java-code

Comment: i wanna create searching on my project using single query java api, then the searching is based on database, i wanna search from all collections mate

on mysql i can use query on the top, or (select * from table1, table2, table3 where table1.name=everest OR table1.age=everest OR table1.hoby=everest OR table2.car=everest OR table2.home=everest OR table2.motorcycle=everest OR table3.phone=everest OR table3.child=everest OR table3.office=everest) but i dunno how to write it using mongoDB for java api

Comment: the link you give, its only using 1 coloumn, i wanna select all coloumn and all table..thanks before for your respone ^^

Answer (score 1):

You may simply fetch all documents for each type:

```
Iterable<Web1> webOnes = mongoTemplate.findAll(Web1.class);
Iterable<Web2> webTwos = mongoTemplate.findAll(Web2.class);
Iterable<Web3> webThrees = mongoTemplate.findAll(Web3.class);
```

Each of your Iterable will contains all documents, with all fields!
Example:

```
for(Web1 web1: webOnes){
    //Accessing your field:  web1.getField()
}
```

For info, if your collections have special names, you will need to specify it in the findAll methods:

```
mongoTemplate.findAll(Model.class, "collectionName");
```

It is really easy to find documentation online, just type mongodb java tutorial, you'll find a lot. Ex: [java-mongodb-tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/)

Also, Mongodb offer a free online course: [M101J](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101J/about)

Comment: can you show me sir?
this one is very new for my programming...
before i only use mysql and oracleSQL, its very different with mongoDB

Comment: Maybe you should go through some tutorials/books before jumping into the code. It would help you to understand the concept first.

Comment: i succes to search by 1 collections and 1 elements here

cursor = table.find(new BasicDBObject("title", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(foundcoloundsite)));

but its so different if having 'or' clause and from many collections..

Comment: sorry i didnt read it before, after i refresh my browser then your full coment is showed...